# I am not able to log in to a page by giving correct username and password

Tags: php

I want to redirect user to log in page if he or she  is not log in. In my  given code, it is redirecting to login page if he or she is not log in  but also 
 redirecting to login page if I give write username and password. I want to 
 redirect to abc.php if he or she give write credentials

here is my login.php

```
   <? php include "db.php";

   $msg = "";

  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
    {
     $username = $_POST["username"];
     $password = $_POST["password"];


   if ($username == '' || $password == '') 
   {
    $msg = "You must enter all fields";
   }
   else 
   {
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password 
     = '$password'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);

     if ($query == false) 
     {
        echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . 
     mysql_error();
        exit;
    }

      $check_user = mysql_num_rows($query);
      if($check_user>0)
      {
     // here you need $run_user data
   // use fetch_ methods, for example `fetch_assoc()`
    $user_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

   // print_r($user_data) to check keys
   if ($user_data["user_role"] == 'admin') 
   {

    header("abc.php");
        exit;
    } 
    else
   {
    if ($user_data["user_role"] == 'user') {
    header("xyz.php");
        exit;//redirect somehwere else
  }
  else
  {
    if($user_data["username"] != '$username' && $user_data["password"] != 
   '$password') 
  {
  echo "invalid username or password";
 exit;
}`

  here is my abc.php
  <?php 

  session_start();
 include "db.php";



  if ((empty($_SESSION['user'])) ){
 header('Location: login.php');
exit;
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: please don't use mysql_*. its deprecated and removed newer versions of php

Comment: `header("xyz.php");` isn't correct. It should be `header('Location: xyz.php');`

Comment: still not working

Comment: please tell me you are not storing unencrypted passwords in db

Answer (score 0):

After successful login you have to save the user details in `$_SESSION['user']`.

Add below code after `$user_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);` --- this line.

`$_SESSION['user']=$user_data;` and `session_start();` should be in your *login.php* file instead of *abc.php*.

Then in your *abc.php* file, `$_SESSION['user']` check will return true in case of successful login. `session_start()` should place before assigning values in session.

Comment: after adding these lines  abc.php is accessible without login.

Comment: you have to add that line in login.php.  read the comments properly.